# how to fix ProtocolException Connection already established in android

Tags: android

```
public static String getJSONfromURL(String URL) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/mobileservice.aspx?service=topstories");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();          
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            connection.connect();



            System.out.println(code);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";

    }
```

This is my code i am Trying  to get response from server but it come Exception Protocol Exception Connection already established i dont  know why this Exception Coming please fix it this Exception where am doing wrong

Comment: why you have this line `connection.connect();` after `os.close();` ?

Comment: Ok wait . let me check

Answer (score 0):

You need to move getResponseCode() after connection.connect(). Like this:

```
                URL url = new URL("https://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/mobileservice.aspx"); //Remove Query Param from Url
                HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();          
                //  int code = connection.getResponseCode();
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                    builder.appendQueryParameter("service", "topstories"); //Add this line
                    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                            os, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(query);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();
                    connection.connect();
                    //Note that above line is irrelevant. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html
                    int code = connection.getResponseCode();//move it here
                    System.out.println(code);

                   if (code == 200) {
                        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                        String line;
                        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                             content.append(line).append("\n");
                        bufferedReader.close();
                        System.out.println(content.toString());
                   }
```

Comment: where i will get Content  as respone

Comment: NO i am unable to get Content

Comment: Updated the answer. You were sending empty query string.